# CORS error after upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, cors, upgrade, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded a relatively large web API from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 and am getting a no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header CORS error. I have not moved to the minimal hosting model, but I understand from the docs that this is not necessary and the old model should continue to work. I include code from startup and program below and what I had to change to make the upgraded project work. Note that everything else works properly.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Get<string[]>())
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
}
```

Note that `*` is returned from "AllowedOrigins".

Program.cs

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    
                    .UseUrls(Configuration.GetValue<bool>("App:UsesHttps") 
                        ? $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("App:HttpUrl")}, " +
                          $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("App:HttpsUrl") }" 
                        : $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("App:HttpUrl")}")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

For the upgrade to .NET 6, nothing in `Startup.cs` has changed. In `Program.cs`, `.UseUrls` does not work anymore and instead I have it defined in appsettings and I have removed the call to `.UseUrls`.

Appsettings (.NET Core 3.1)

```
"App": {
        "UsesHttps": false,
        "HttpUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5005",
        "HttpsUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
    },
```

Appsettings (.NET 6)

```
"Kestrel": {
        "Endpoints": {
            "Http": {
                "Url": "http://localhost:5005"
            }
        }
    },
```

Nothing else in the code has changed, and all I have done is update packages. I fail to see how they would influence a CORS error.

The app is running in a Docker container behind Nginx serving as a reverse proxy. I have not made any changed to the Nginx settings. The app is listening on HTTP only as Nginx handles the HTTPS connection. Again, this works when the app is built against .NET Core 3.1. I have read the documentation about upgrading to .NET 6 and I cannot find anything that would explain this kind of a change.

Comment: Don't know if it'll help, but have a look at my comprehensive [upgrade checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984529/9971404), there could be something you've missed. Could be the problem is actually not related to CORS, but some other config.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this will help you. We have the following in our API in the program.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Other code left out here

        app.UseAuthentication();

        // Allow CORS for any origin, method or header
        app.UseCors(policy =>
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthorization();

     }
```

If I remember correctly the order of things is pretty important. I don't see Authentication and Authorization in your code. Don't know if you need that or not. There's a remark at this code as it might be allowing too much. We still have to investigate that.

Comment: I have both `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` in `Startup.cs`. I have them palced after the CORS policy, but I confirmed that this was the order in the .NET Core project as well and to my knowledge nothing has changed such that the order would need to be different now than it was before.